# Flask скачивание txt

Tags: python, flask

как я могу реализовать скачивание файла после его создания скриптом? Пример: пользователь заполняет форму на сайте, я с помощью GET,POST ловлю данные, обрабатываю их и потом скачиваю пользователю файл.(при этом пользователь нажал только на 1 кнопку и данные обрабатываются несколько секунд) Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете папку и путь к ней указывайте в `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']`:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'images'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

Заводите маршрут для возврата файла и используйте [send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory):

```
@app.route('/' + UPLOAD_FOLDER + '/<file_name>')
def images(file_name):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name, as_attachment=True)
```

Путь до файла из скрипта можно так получить:

```
uri = url_for(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name=file_name)
```

---

**PS.**

Код брал (и адаптировал) из сервера по генерации и скачиванию QR code, и, возможно, он будет вам полезен [как пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/992595fc6558423141c0834a4ad4b389e8d60684/flask__webservers/generate_qrcode/main.py).

**PPS.**

Импорты:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, url_for
```